# Cordova build failed processDebugResources

Tags: android, cordova, plugins

**I'm trying to compile my cordova app for android, but I get the next error:**

```
Execution failed for task ':processDebugResources'. Error: more than one library with package name 'com.google.android.gms'
```

**This is my plugin list**

`com.pylonproducts.wifiwizard 0.2.11 "WifiWizard"
cordova-google-play-services 25.0.0 "Google Play Services for Android"
cordova-plugin-compat 1.1.0 "Compat"
cordova-plugin-device 1.1.2 "Device"
cordova-plugin-facebook4 1.9.1 "Facebook Connect"
cordova-plugin-geolocation 2.4.3 "Geolocation"
cordova-plugin-network-information 1.2.1 "Network Information"
cordova-plugin-splashscreen 3.2.2 "Splashscreen"
cordova-plugin-statusbar 2.1.3 "StatusBar"
cordova-plugin-whitelist 1.2.2 "Whitelist"
ionic-plugin-keyboard 2.2.1 "Keyboard"
onesignal-cordova-plugin 2.1.2 "OneSignal Push Notifications"`

This happens whenever I try to compile with both **'onesignal-cordova-plugin' and 'cordova-google-play-serivces'**.

I've tried changing my build.gradle from this:

```
compile "com.google.android.gms:play-services-gcm:+"
compile "com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:+"
```

to this:

```
compile "com.google.android.gms:play-services-gcm:10.2+"
compile "com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:10.2+"
```

and some other versions but none has worked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Resolved it by changing

```
onesignal-cordova-plugin 2.1.2 "OneSignal Push Notifications"
```

for

```
onesignal-cordova-plugin-pgb-compat 1.13.1 "OneSignal Push Notifications PGB Compat"
```